# Is there a way of installing OptaPy in Kaggle?

Tags: kaggle, optapy

I want to try out OptaPy in a Kaggle notebook, but I fell at the first hurdle when I tried to install it:

```
!pip install optapy
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 8.11.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.11.0a1 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.11.0a2 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.14.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.16.1a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.17.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.19.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.19.0a1 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.21.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.23.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement optapy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for optapy
```

The Kaggle environment appears to be: Python version: 3.7.12 | Java version: 11.0.15

Any thoughts on a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

From the error message:

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 8.11.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.11.0a1 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.11.0a2 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.14.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.16.1a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.17.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.19.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.19.0a1 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.21.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 8.23.0a0 Requires-Python >=3.9
```

From https://www.kaggle.com/general/173536, it seems Kaggle uses Python 3.7 and does not provide a direct way to upgrade. OptaPy requires Python 3.9 or higher (it uses 3.9 syntax in its sources, so 3.8 and below won't work).